# Worker Role hiding console process

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to execute a console process in my worker role but no matter what configuration I set to the process it is always running in background :

These are my console settings :

```
Process proc = new Process();

proc.StartInfo.FileName = "D:\\ZProcessing.exe" ; //console process

proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;

proc.Start();
```

Comment: Running the the background, or running as another user?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
private IntPtr handle;
private Process proc;

private void MyMethod()
{
  proc = new Process();
  proc.StartInfo.FileName = "D:\\ZProcessing.exe" ; //console process

  proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
  proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
  proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
  proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;

  proc.Start();

  // Find new window handle
  handle = proc.MainWindowHandle;

  // Set it to foreground
  SetForegroundWindow(handle);
}
```

Unfortunately this isn't possible using pure .NET, for as far as I know. The above is a solution under the assumption that you are running the process under the same user as the currently logged on user.